# Laser Rangefinder Webcam DIY Python

Tags: python, editing

After researching all over the web for a DIY laser range finder webcam; I found a cool project that finds the distance of the laser in cm. I was wondering if someone can help me change some lines of code so that it can measure the distance in yards with decimals( to act like fractions).
Here is the link to the website I found [webcam laser rangefinder](https://shaneormonde.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/webcam-laser-rangefinder/)

I don't know anything about trigonometry and I know nothing beyond high school algebra and geometry that I remember. In other words, I don't understand the math that this link is talking about; which is why, I am asking someone to show me an example of what the code would look like if it measured in yards instead of centimeters. Thank you in advanced.

Here is the code

```
     ## program written by Shane Ormonde 7th sept 2013
     ## updated on 25th January 2014
     ## calculates the distance of a red dot in the field of view of the webcam.

    import cv2
    from numpy import *
    import math

    #variables
    loop = 1

    dot_dist = 0

    cv2.namedWindow("preview")
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(1)



    if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()

    else:
            rval = False
     #print "failed to open webcam"


    if rval == 1 :

           while loop == 1:
        cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
        rval, frame = vc.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27: # exit on ESC
            loop = 0
        num = (frame[...,...,2] > 236)
        xy_val =  num.nonzero()

        y_val = median(xy_val[0])
        x_val = median(xy_val[1])

        dist = ((x_val - 320)**2 + (y_val - 240)**2 )**0.5 # distance of dot from center pixel
        dist = abs(x_val - 320) # distance of dot from center x_axis only

        print " dist from center pixel is " + str(dist) 

        # work out distance using D = h/tan(theta)

        theta =0.0011450*dist + 0.0154         
        tan_theta = math.tan(theta)



        if tan_theta > 0: # bit of error checking
            obj_dist =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)


        print "\033[12;0H" + "the dot is " + str(obj_dist) + "cm  away"
        elif rval == 0:
          print " webcam error "
```

Comment: So you have the distance in yards, and have to convert it to meters (or cm, etc..)?

Comment: @Miki, no he has it in cm and wants yards.

Comment: @sommerjj ok, However, if that's the topic of the question, that  has noting to do with opencv. Nor C++ (since your code is in python). Nor trigonometry. Nor any laser or any webcam. It's just a conversion. So, if you have the distance and want to convert to another metric system, ask that and edit your question accordingly. If you don't have the distance yet, but you need to find it (in any metric system), then please edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is for people looking for answers to problems they've attempted to solve but cannot find a solution. It is not a code writing service.

Comment: Its going to take some time for me to learn how to program. I'm trying to become a programmer while I am in college(not now I don't take summer classes).I'm a noob that is trying to get a fresh start ahead so I started studying java and I can make very primitive programs like hello world and interactive equation solvers in text. Yes, I know that the code above is python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that yards = centimeters * 0.010936

Change this block:

```
if tan_theta > 0: # bit of error checking
    obj_dist =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)
```

To this:

```
if tan_theta > 0: # bit of error checking
    obj_dist =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)
    #convert from centimeters to yards
    obj_dist = obj_dist * 0.010936
```

If we look at the part where it tell us how far the dot is, we see the line `print "\033[12;0H" + "the dot is " + str(obj_dist) + "cm  away"`.  This tells us that the distance is stored in the variable `obj_dist`.  So I looked back through the code to find out how obj_dist got its value.  The only other time `obj_dist` is referenced is on the line: `obj_dist =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)`.  Another way to view that line is `obj_dist = centimters_away`.  So to get yards, all we have to do is add a line that converts `obj_dist` from centimeters to yards, which is what I did.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! I guess asking questions does make you learn easier than reading a book and studying it for hours.